# ¿Cómo acceder a las propiedades de un objeto dentro de una Lista?

Tags: c#

Estoy utilizando una lista para guardar objetos, cada uno con sus propiedades. Mi problema es que no puedo acceder a las propiedades de los objetos de esa lista para editarlas programáticamente. Mi clase `Program` se ve así:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextosApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Inicializa un Anotador
        Anotador anotador = new Anotador();

        //La interfaz inicia y pregunta que hacer
        Console.WriteLine("Qué desea hacer? Tipee 'ayuda' para más información.");
        Console.WriteLine("Inserte un comando: ");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        bool salir = true;

        //Loop del programa
        while (salir)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input == "agregar")
            {
               anotador.AgregarTexto();
               Console.WriteLine("");
               Console.WriteLine("Texto agregado con éxito.");
               Console.WriteLine("");
               Console.WriteLine("Inserte un comando:");
               Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else if (input == "listar")
            {
               Console.WriteLine("");
               anotador.ListarTextos();
               Console.WriteLine("");
               Console.WriteLine("Inserte un comando: ");
               Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else if (input == "ayuda")
            {
               Console.WriteLine("");
               Console.WriteLine("Los comandos disponibles son: agregar - listar - ayuda - salir");
               Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else if (input == "editar")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Inserte el Id/Numero de texto a editar");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                int id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                anotador.EditarTexto(id);
            }
            else if (input == "salir")
            {
               salir = false;
            }
            else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("");
               Console.WriteLine("Inserte un comando válido: ");
               Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando `editar`, paso el parámetro `Id` al método correspondiente, que realiza lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextosApp
{
class Anotador
{

    public Anotador()
    {
        textos = new List<object>();
    }

    public void AgregarTexto()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Inserte un nombre para su texto:");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        textos.Add(new Texto()
        {
            Id = textos.Count,
            Leido = false,
            Nombre = Console.ReadLine()
        });
    }

    public void ListarTextos()
    {
        if (textos.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Texto texto in textos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Número: " + texto.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Nombre del texto: " + texto.Nombre);
                Console.WriteLine(texto.Leido ? "(Has leido este texto.)" : "(No has leido este texto.)");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No hay textos!");
        }

    }

    public void EditarTexto(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el nuevo texto: ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string nuevoTexto = Console.ReadLine();
        textos[id].Nombre = nuevoTexto;
    }

    public List<object> textos;

}
}
```

Sin embargo es allí donde tengo problemas porque no puedo acceder a `Nombre`. Sí puedo acceder a `textos[id]`, pero no a sus propiedades. Mi clase `Texto` se ve así:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextosApp
{
    class Texto //Clase simple
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public bool Leido { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: La próxima vez, trata de seguir las pautas para crear un buen [mcve], que no tenga un exceso de código innecesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y por el consejo. La próxima vez seguiré las pautas al publicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes acceder a la propiedad `Nombre` en esta sentencia:

```
textos[id].Nombre = nuevoTexto;
```

... porque `textos[id]` es de tipo `object`, no `Texto`.  Esto es porque tu lista `textos` la tienes declarada como una lista de objetos:

```
public List<object> textos;
```

Cambia la declaración de la lista para indicar que contiene instancias de la clase `Texto`:

```
public List<Texto> textos;
```

... también tienes que cambiar donde le asignas una nueva instancia:

```
public Anotador()
{
    textos = new List<Texto>();
}
```

Ahora sí podrás acceder las propiedades de `Texto` sin problema.

Comment: La otra opción es hacer casting: ((Texto) textos[Id]).Nombre = nuevoTexto;